# Différence entre « souhait » et « désir »

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot, synonymes

Est-ce mieux d'écrire:  « La conseillère conforme aux souhaits du client » ou « La conseillère conforme aux désirs du client » ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

S'il s'agit d'un phrase complète, on **doit**<sup>1</sup> utiliser *conformer* à la forme pronominale:

> La conseillère **se** conforme aux désirs des clients.
>
> La conseillère **se** conforme aux souhaits des clients.

Les deux mots ont alors des sens suffisamment proches pour être utilisés indifféremment.

Cependant, une petite différence est que *désir*, plus de l'ordre émotionnel, peut avoir une connotation sexuelle que *souhait*, plus réfléchi, n'a pas.

Suivant le contexte, la deuxième phrase pourra alors être préférée.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>La phrase ***la conseillère conforme aux désirs des clients*** est impossible si *conforme* est la troisième personne du singulier du verbe conformer, que ce soit en français moderne ou plus ancien. If faudrait au minimum un complément comme dans ***la conseillère conforme son travail aux désirs des clients***, mais ce n'est pas une tournure courante. S'il s'agit d'un adjectif, l'expression n'est pas incorrecte grammaticalement parlant, mais n'a pas beaucoup de sens. On pourrait plutôt écrire, ***la conseillère, conformément aux désirs/souhaits des clients,...***</sub>

Comment: Cette idée de connotations sexuelles dans ce contexte est aberrante, c'est un glissement arbitraire insensé justifié par rien du tout ; les objets du désir constituent une masse énorme de concepts dans laquelle la sexualité n'est qu'une goutte d'eau.

Comment: @LPH *Et le désir s’accroît quand l'effet se recule.*

Comment: Voici une partie de la réponse que j'ai reçue dans un autre forum : Si on évoque l’aspiration des clients à posséder des biens que l’entreprise commercialise, désir est sémantiquement plus adapté. Mais il peut connoter un certain sens sexuel…

Comment: @Dimitris, Intéressant de constater que les deux réponses de [ce forum](https://www.question-orthographe.fr/question/difference-entre-souhait-et-desir/) ont comme la mienne évoqué la connotation possible physique / sexuelle, alors que tu as pourtant modifié la phrase en remplaçant *la secrétaire* par *l'entreprise*, ce qui réduisait beaucoup ce risque.

Answer (score 1):

On compare d'abord les définitions des deux mots.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/d%C3%A9sir)) DÉSIR B. 1. [Le substantif est au singulier avec l'article « un », ou au pluriel] Aspiration instinctive de l'être à combler le sentiment d'un manque, d'une incomplétude.
>
> - Un désir confus, fugitif, profond.
>
> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/souhait) SOUHAIT A. Désir, exprimé ou non par quelqu'un, d'obtenir quelque chose pour lui ou un autre, de voir un événement se produire.
>
> - Synon. vœu.

On voit à partir de cela qu'un souhait n'est qu'un désir, et de plus que ce n'est pas  un type particulier de désir puisque « obtenir pour soi ou un autre, voir un évènement se produire » implique « combler le sentiment d'un manque, d'une incomplétude » ; ce qui n'est pas ne peut ne pas être que soit pour nous, soit pour les autres, soit dans le monde des évènements.

Si on compare les listes des [synonymes](http://www.synonymo.fr/syno/souhait) « occasionnels » pour les deux mots on trouve qu'ils tendent à être des synonymes parfaits puisque chacun est dans la liste de l'autre.

*Synonymes de désir*

amativité, appétence, appétit, appel, ardeur, éros, aspiration, attente, attirance, attrait, avidité,
besoin, bouillonnement, boulimie, but, caprice, chaleur,
concupiscence, convoitise, cupidité, curiosité, démangeaison, demande, desiderata, dessein, envie, espérance, espoir, exigence, faim, fantaisie, feu, flamme, force, goût, humeur, idée, impatience, inclination, intérêt, intention, libido, objectif, penchant, prétention, propos, prurit, rêve, rapacité, résolution, revendication, salacité, sensualité, soif, souhait, tendance, tentation, vanité, velléité, visée, vœu, volonté

*Synonymes de «souhait »*

ambition, appétit, aspiration, attente, convoitise, désir, demande, desiderata, desideratum, envie, faim, optation, résolution, revendication, soif

Je pense donc que l'on peut utiliser  soit l'un soit l'autre des deux mots sans diverger appréciablement de l'idée qu'il est question d'une chose plus ou moins voulue ; cependant il semble qu'il y ait dans le mot « souhait » une nuance qui en fait un terme légèrement moins catégorique que « désir » et qui tend à communiquer, au lieu d'un désir formel, plutôt un espoir.

> [Encyclopédie libre](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Souhait) Un souhait, ou vœu, est un espoir ou un désir qu'un événement s'accomplisse.

---

*Ajout suscité par le commentaire de [user **jlliagre**](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/41072/difference-entre-souhait-et-d%c3%a9sir#comment82806_41072)*

Il faut considérer tout d'abord que le verbe utilisé est « conformer qqc à qqc » qui peut très bien s'utiliser intransitivement et qui signifie

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/conformer)) «  Mettre une chose en accord, en harmonie avec une autre prise pour modèle »,

alors que le verbe qui pourrait sembler convenir dans le présent contexte  est le verbe pronominal « se conformer  à qqc », celui-ci signifiant

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/conformer)) « Se régler sur, se mettre en accord avec », ou bien,

> « Se soumettre à ».

On dirait donc plutôt « La conseillère se conforme aux désirs/souhaits du client » en français moderne et ce sera ce qu'il faut dire si l'on entend utiliser le verbe dans le sens que la conseillère « obéit aux désirs du client » (attitude cependant seulement accessoire au travail d'un conseiller), mais il est plus logique de concevoir que la conseillère adapte un système au désirs du client plutôt que de voir la chose sous l'aspect  d'une conseillère qui se  met elle-même en accord : ce sont les règles qu'elle met en accord. Évidemment cet usage est rare, on trouve une utilisation massive du verbe pronominal en français moderne.

Answer (score 0):

Voir ici : http://portail.atilf.fr/cgi-bin/getobject_?a.30:150./var/artfla/encyclopedie/textdata/IMAGE/

> Ces mots désignent en général le sentiment par lequel nous aspirons à quelque chose ; avec cette différence que désir ajoute un degré de vivacité à l'idée de souhait, & que souhait est quelquefois uniquement de compliment & de politesse: ainsi on dit les désirs d'une âme chrétienne, les souhaits de la nouvelle année.

Un article contemporain : http://mfmeuron.blog.tdg.ch/archive/2018/08/03/quelles-distinctions-entre-le-souhait-l-envie-le-desir-l-asp-293500.html

> Lorsque nous émettons un souhait (nom masculin !), nous exprimons une formulation. Toutefois, nous utilisons le conditionnel qui est construit sur du passé et du futur. Nous ne sommes par conséquent pas dans l’instant présent, dans la réalité concrète. Lorsque nous exprimons un désir (nom masculin!), notre être tout entier ressent une pulsion globale.

Tu peux aussi voir ce thread ici : https://fr.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110710183215AA5lCoF

Étant non locuteur natif, je dirais : >La conseillère **se** conforme aux désirs du client.

**edit**

J'ai posé la question sur un autre forum (projet Voltaire) :

https://www.question-orthographe.fr/question/difference-entre-souhait-et-desir/

Voici les réponses :

> Désir et souhait sont synonymes avec de fortes nuances, puisque désir peut avoir (parmi tous les sens possibles) un sens physique. Donc souhait est peut-être plus neutre.  Ce n’est qu’une impression personnelle. Pour l’aspect commercial, on utilise parfois des termes moins affectifs : besoins, attentes, demande…
>
> Dictionnaire de l’Académie française :
>
> Souhait : « Vœu, désir qu’une chose s’accomplisse. Souhait ardent.
>   Souhait imprudent, téméraire. Faire un souhait. Former des souhaits.
>   Il a obtenu l’accomplissement de ses souhaits les plus chers. »
>
> Désir : « Vive aspiration à la possession d’un objet, d’un bien, d’un
>   avantage. Le désir du gain, des richesses, des honneurs. Le désir du
>   savoir, du bien. Le désir de l’absolu, de Dieu. » Peut évoquer le
>   désir sexuel.
>
> Si on évoque l’aspiration des clients à posséder des biens que
>   l’entreprise commercialise, désir est sémantiquement plus adapté. Mais
>   il peut connoter un certain sens sexuel…